# Should I use "here" or "there" in the following sentence?

Tags: word-choice

> Sophia was awakened by the rattling sound of the alarm clock. Rubbing her
>   eyes, she sat up, and after fumbling for a while, she finally managed
>   to turn the alarm off. She lay on her back again, wondering why
>   David had to set the alarm on Sunday. But when she looked to **the side**
>   to ask him, she realized he was no longer **here/there**.

Should I use **here** or **there** in the passage above?

Comment: There, because David doesn't sleep in the same space that she does, does he?

Comment: @mikhailcazi, that does not matter. ‘Here’ does not necessarily have to be the _exact_ same place as something else.

Comment: Off topic (request for writing advice).

Comment: See my comment at Andrew Leach below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use ***there.***

The reason is that you are writing from the point of view of a third party who has observed events and is relating them as having occurred in the past.

*Here* relates to the place at the side of Sophia. From the **point of the view of the narrator,** that is *there* because it is not where the narrator is.

Comment: So, if he were still 'there' the narrator should have used 'here'? It is unclear what relevance the time frame has in this context.

Comment: He isn't there: he's writing in the past tense. If the work were re-cast in the present tense it becomes more tenable, but even then *there* is to be preferred because it means "in that place" and "in this place" would still not be correct.

Comment: -1 *Here* & *there* are not antonyms -- they mean different things. *There* is more often used as a dummy (like the existential it) in such constructions than to mean something 'distant'. That way, both can be correct. There's also a 'rule' about 'this' vs. 'that' which is another aspect again. It's not so simple to decide.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew is right. You might also want to think about changing ‘when she looked to the side’. It almost sounds as if you mean she turned away. Perhaps make it more explicit with something like ‘when she looked over to his side of the bed’.

Comment: _When she turned to ask him_ flows better

Comment: Wouldn't *there* be like the existential *it* in the sentence?

Comment: I don't think so. It's definitely deictic.

Answer (score 0):

Of course the answer must be 'there' as some narrator[third person] is telling all this for him it would be 'there' not 'here'.

Answer (score 0):

She (here) looked to 'the side' (there).

I think that the tense is relevant but I'm not sure how to explain it well.  If she were talking in the present she would say 'he isn't here' (right next to me right now).  To say in the present, 'he isn't there' suggests some distance from the speaker, like in another room for example.  Can someone help with the rule about the tense?

Comment: Wait, I got confused.  It is 'there' because of the narrator.  But if Sophia was speaking then I think my point would still stand.